# Powershell Create gui objects with values in test.txt

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have been searching all over the interwebs and have been unable to find an answer. Maybe I am searching for the wrong things. I am trying to read a text file and have it update the GUI menu bar. What I have is:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem $FilePath 
Foreach($file in $folder){
    $(Filename)= new-system System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
    $(filename).Name = "$(filename)"
    $(filename).Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(35, 20)
    $(filename).Text = "&(filename)"
    $(foldername).item.add($(Name of file))
    $var = get-content c:\test\$file
    foreach($line in $var){
        $A = $line.split("^")
        $(Name of object) = new-system System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        $(Name of object).Name = "$a[0]"
        $(Name of object).Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(35, 20)
        $(Name of object).Text = "&$a[1]"
        $(FileName).item.add($(Name of object))
```

How can I get it to create different Variable names for the files and for each line in it? I hope I have made my request clear enough. Each file will have no more then 20 lines to read from.

Comment: And now that I have asked I have found it.

    `for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
    {
    New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value $i
    Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
    }`

How would I reference that information within my loops?

Comment: Alright finally found a way
`$var = get-content c:\test\links.txt
foreach($line in $var){
    $A = $line.split("^")
    $variablename = "$"+ "var0"+ $a[0]
    $createObject = "$Variablename = new-object system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem"
    $settext = "$variablename.text = $a[0]"
    $setsize = "$variablename.size = new-object System.drawing.size(35,20)"
    $addmenu = "$ToolStripMenuItem.item.add($variablename)"
    Invoke-expression $createObject 
    Invoke-expression $settext
    Invoke-expression $setsize
    Invoke-expression $addmenu
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = get-content c:\test\links.txt
foreach($line in $var){
$A = $line.split("^")
$variablename = "$"+ "var0"+ $a[0]
$createObject = "$Variablename = new-object system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem"
$settext = "$variablename.text = $a[0]"
$setsize = "$variablename.size = new-object System.drawing.size(35,20)"
$addmenu = "$ToolStripMenuItem.item.add($variablename)"
Invoke-expression $createObject 
Invoke-expression $settext
Invoke-expression $setsize
Invoke-expression $addmenu
}
```